# add animation to fill progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i update it to fill progress bar with animation?

https://jsfiddle.net/dfkLexuv/2/

```css
.progress-bar-outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  flex: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
}

.progress-bar-inner {
  /* You can change the `width` to change the amount of progress. */
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.progress-bar-inner2 {
  /* You can change the `width` to change the amount of progress. */
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar-outer">
  <div class="progress-bar-inner">
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar-inner2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416077/css3-keyframe-progress-bar)

Comment: If you're looking for a JavaScript solution please post what you've tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it https://jsfiddle.net/f1ajv0Lv/5/

You would then need to add JS to update the `scaleX` style as the progress changes:

```
$progressBar.css('transform', 'scaleX(' + percentageCompleteFromZeroToOne + ')');
```

Note that I added some additional attributes for better accessibility:

```
<div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">20 %</div>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_progressbar_role

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see any animation.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't add the JS to update the progress bar position since I don’t know where you are getting the info from. If you are trying to animate without JS, let me know and I will update the demo!

Answer (score 0):

A small, basic, demo of how to use JavaScript to animate a progress bar :

```js
var $progressBarOuter = $('.progress-bar-outer');
var $progressBar = $('.progress-bar-inner');

setTimeout(function() {
$progressBar.css('width', '10%');
setTimeout(function() {
    $progressBar.css('width', '30%');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $progressBar.css('width', '100%');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $progressBarOuter.css('display', 'none');
            console.log('LOADING COMPLETE');
        }, 500); // WAIT 5 milliseconds
    }, 2000); // WAIT 2 seconds
}, 1000); // WAIT 1 seconds
}, 1000); // WAIT 1 second
```

```css
.progress-bar-outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  flex: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

.progress-bar-inner {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar-outer">
  <div class="progress-bar-inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this guy a shot!

add this to your head tag.

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

then add some js.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".progress-bar-inner" ).animate({
    width:"100%"
  }, 5000);

  $( ".progress-bar-inner2" ).animate({
        width:0
   }, 5000);

});
```

I modified the css a bit also.

```
.progress-bar-outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  flex: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
}
.progress-bar-inner {
  /* You can change the `width` to change the amount of progress. */
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.progress-bar-inner2 {
  /* You can change the `width` to change the amount of progress. */
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```